# Change order of activity to open first

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a project, where i have 4 activities. Each time i run the project, activityA opens first and then other activities, but i want that the MainActivity should open first and then other activities.

Where should i define the order of activities to open.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.it"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

          <activity android:name=".GeneralAct" />
          <activity android:name=".BackUp" />
          <activity android:name=".AccountSettings" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define MainActivity as,

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and all other activities as,

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Launcher** Activity is opened first and then the **Default** Activities.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

within the activity tag for MainActivity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MAinActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Activity you want to open first must have a intent filter with category description as:

```
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Here is the complete Activity declaration in Android Menifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/app_theme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your manifest with this code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.it"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity android:name=".GeneralAct" />
      <activity android:name=".BackUp" />
      <activity android:name=".AccountSettings" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".yourmainactivityname"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--   Activity1 -->
    <activity android:name=".Activity1" />

    <!--  Activity2 -->
    <activity android:name=".Activity2 " />

    <!--   Activity3 -->
    <activity android:name=".Activity3 " />
      <!--   Activity4 -->
     <activity android:name=".Activity4" />
</application>
```